# grails2, springsecurity and static resources (css, js, etc.)

Tags: grails, spring-security

Happy New Year!
To start the year on the right foot, I'm trying to bolt down my app with the help of springsecurity plugin.

Came across the Pessimistic Lockdown section of the plugin docs and the following indeed locked everything down:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.rejectIfNoRule = true
```

... but how do I 'unlock' css, js and image files? I'm able to unlock all the controllers and actions that I need to be publicly accessible, but not the css files.

At the moment my Config.groovy has this:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.rejectIfNoRule = true;

grails.plugins.springsecurity.securityConfigType = SecurityConfigType.InterceptUrlMap

grails.plugins.springsecurity.interceptUrlMap = [

        '/admin/**' : ['ROLE_ADMIN', 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY'],
        '/css/**': ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'],
        '/login/auth': ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'],
        '/*':               ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY']
]
```

the '/*' keeps the home page visible, but the css is blocked.
Thanks in advance

Comment: springsecurity depends on the WebXml plugin. Can you look into your application.properties and check which version of this plugin you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have any experience with `grails.plugins.springsecurity.rejectIfNoRule = true` but I believe the following interceptUrlMap would be equivalent

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.interceptUrlMap = [
    '/js/**':                               ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'],
    '/css/**':                              ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'],
    '/images/**':                           ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'],
    '/login/auth':                          ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'],
    '/':                                    ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'],
    '/admin/**':                            ['ROLE_ADMIN', 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY'],
    '/**':                                  ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY']
```

Having js, css, and images at the top ensures no other rules conflict with them and `/**` at the end acts as a catch-all for anything that doesn't match first. Give that a shot and see if it works better.

Comment: ... good deal! In dev, the url looks like http://localhost:8080/MyApp/index.html so the js and css files also are served from http://localhost:8080/MyApp/js/some.js for instance. So the first rule looks like '/**/js/** ..... and all's well. I ended up creating separate configs for the den and prod environment.

Answer (score 1):

Are the static resource directories getting served under the `<context-name>/static/` path, i.e. `my-app/static/css` instead of `my-app/css` in the generated HTML?  I've been working on a Grails 2.0 app and noticed that css, images and js directories are now moved to that path seemingly by default, which is different that Grails 1.3.

I believe it's the new resources plugin that's causing the URL change, but haven't used the spring-security plugin in 2.0 yet to verify that this is the problem.

Comment: ... no, my-app/css/some-styles.css for example, I just checked it :-(

Comment: I was surprised to see the whole /static/ thing, it just worked like that by default when I generated my project.  And if I make a request without the /static/ in the URL, it just redirects to the same resource but with the /static/.